# Strings: Finding if the first word is repeated using strcmp

Tags: c++, string, strcmp

I have an assignment where I have to type in the amount of names I want to compare. Then I have to see if the first name printed is repeated in the names I printed. For example if I put in 5 Reagan, Bush, Reagan, Bush, Clinton it will print out "The first name was repeated" but if I put in Davis for either of the Reagans it would say no. I've attempted a for loop and if statements but I can't seem to find the correct output. I am using Dev C++ and here is what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main () {
    char curname[30], firstname[30];
    int num, i, freq = 1;


    printf("How many names do you want to enter?\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("What is the first name?");
    scanf("%s", firstname); 
    printf("Enter each of their names.\n");
    for (i=0; i<num; i++) {

        scanf("%s", curname);

        if (i==0) {
          strcmp(curname, firstname) != 0;
          printf("The first name in the list was repeated.\n"); 
        }
        else if (strcmp(curname, firstname) == 1)
          printf("The first name in the list was not repeated.\n"); 
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This line seems suspicious `if (i==0) {` as this will mean that the comparison is only run for the first name entered.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  You've tagged this question with C++, but the code you show is not using any distinctive features of C++ at all and could perfectly well be tagged as C. At first sight, it look as though your code won't compile; that is always a serious problem. _However_, it does compile — but your placement of the close braces is very confusing. The one after the last `printf()` actually terminates the `for` loop. Please go and learn a standard layout — Allman style or the OTBS (One True Brace Style). You can search for those easily enough.

Comment: @kaitlyn - I have edited your layout, Hopefully you can see what Jonathan is pointing out about layout. Better layout avoids logic problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do only one comparison and print your message based on the result of that comparison.

```
    if (strcmp(curname, firstname) == 0 ) {
      printf("The first name in the list was repeated.\n"); 
    }
    else {
      printf("The first name in the list was not repeated.\n"); 
    }
```

Its always worthwhile to be very clear on what the return value of any function call is, in this case strcmp.

Comment: When you say be very clear on the return value do you mean the return 0; part? If so how would I change that? And thank you!

Comment: I am meaning the strcmp return code value, in this case 0 indicating the strings are the same, but generally you can also find an alternative function such as stricmp.  In other words read the manual :)

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` return value may be greater 0 or less then 0, so:

```
strcmp(curname, firstname) == 1
```

change to:

```
strcmp(curname, firstname) != 0
```

others: You did not record the names into a list, so you can not find the name if or not repeated.

Comment: I ended up deleting a set of curly braces which allowed my to enter the names in a list. Unfortunately I am still getting the wrong output message. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you have to compare names, strcmpi is more appropriate (case insensitive comparison)

```
 if (strcmpi(curname, firstname)==0)
    printf("The first name in the list was repeated.\n"); 
 else 
    printf("The first name in the list was not repeated.\n");
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll talk to my teacher about it! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So I have edited my program based on the suggestions. Here is what I have now. It will only give me the correct output if the name is entered as the last value. Thank you so much!! :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main () {
char curname[30], firstname[30];
int num, i, freq = 1;

// Read in the number of students.
printf("How many names do you want to enter?\n");
scanf("%d", &num);
printf("What is the first name?\n");
scanf("%s", firstname); 
printf("Enter each of their names.\n");
for (i=0; i<num; i++) 

// Read the current name.
scanf("%s", curname);

// Always update the best seen for the first name.
if (strcmp(firstname, curname)== 0)  {
    printf("The first name in the list was repeated.\n"); }
 else
    printf("The first name in the list was not repeated.\n"); 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```